# Checkboxes and icons margin and padding not visually good as the original ones

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-design-system

folks!

I am trying to replicate a record detail layout's from a object into my LWC. But, the checkbox and the pencils icons padding and margin are not equal as the original one, why?

I did create a external css file into my LWC's folder, but not even a single change...

Actual (my LWC): [image]

```
<template>
    <template if:true={account}>
        <div
            class="test-id__section slds-m-vertical_none slds-section has-header slds-p-bottom_medium slds-is-open">
            <h3 class="test-id__section-header-container slds-section__title" onclick={toggleSectorOfOperation}>
                <button aria-controls="sectionContent-392" aria-expanded="true"
                    class="test-id__section-header-button slds-section__title-action slds-button">
                    <span class="test-id__section-header-icon slds-icon_container slds-m-right_x-small">
                        <lightning-icon icon-name="utility:chevrondown" size="x-small">
                        </lightning-icon>
                    </span>
                    <span class="test-id__section-header-title slds-truncate">Sector of Operation</span>
                </button>
            </h3>
            <div
                class="test-id__section-content slds-section__content section__content slds-p-horizontal_small">
                <template if:true={sectorOfOperationSection}>
                    <div class="slds-form">
                        <div class="slds-form__row">
                            <div class="slds-form__item slds-no-space">
                                <div class="slds-size_1-of-2">
                                    <lightning-record-form record-id={recordId} object-api-name="Account"
                                        fields={re} mode="view">
                                    </lightning-record-form>
                                </div>
                                <div class="slds-size_1-of-2">
                                    <lightning-record-form record-id={recordId} object-api-name="Account"
                                        fields={infra} mode="view">
                                    </lightning-record-form>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </template>
            </div>
        </div>
    </template>
</template>
```

Expected (Record Detail): [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

by using the `lightning-record-form` component, you are basically giving up any sort of control over your UI in exchange of convenience and ease of use. If you want to mimic the record layout's, you are better off using the [SLDS blueprints](http://spring-16.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/forms). You might get away with part of the overhead by using a [lightning-record-edit](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-record-edit-form) form + blueprint components .